# AVAssetExportSession issue with AVAssetExportPreset type

Tags: ios, swift, avasset

I am using this extension to save video file from `AVAsset` to the tmp folder. Problem is that when I am using `AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality` type video files could not be saved due to that reason:

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could
>   not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1748482e0 {Error
>   Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12780 "(null)"},
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12780),
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}

Also some times even when I am using `AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality` it saves video but in random order.

```
extension AVAsset {

    func write(to url: URL, success: @escaping () -> (), failure: @escaping (Error) -> ()) {
        guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: self, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality) else {
            let error = NSError(domain: "domain", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
            failure(error)

            return
        }

        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
        exportSession.outputURL = url

        exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
            switch exportSession.status {
            case .completed:
                success()
            case .unknown, .waiting, .exporting, .failed, .cancelled:
                let error = NSError(domain: "domain", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
                failure(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is connected with wrong length of the `AVAsset` components. For some reason `AVAsset` tracks have different duration of the video and audio tracks and it was the main issue.

To solve this issue I am using custom extension of the `AVAsset`.This function will create new `AVAsset` based on video and audio tracks with condition that will fix duration issue. So `AVAsset` obtained from `normalizingMediaDuration()` could be successfully exported.

```
extension AVAsset {
    func normalizingMediaDuration() -> AVAsset? {
        let mixComposition : AVMutableComposition = AVMutableComposition()
        var mutableCompositionVideoTrack : [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
        var mutableCompositionAudioTrack : [AVMutableCompositionTrack] = []
        let totalVideoCompositionInstruction : AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()

        guard let video = tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).first else {
            return nil
        }

        guard let audio = tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio).first else {
            return nil
        }

        mutableCompositionVideoTrack.append(mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
        mutableCompositionAudioTrack.append(mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

        let duration = video.timeRange.duration.seconds > audio.timeRange.duration.seconds ? audio.timeRange.duration : video.timeRange.duration

        do{
            try mutableCompositionVideoTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,duration), of: video, at: kCMTimeZero)
            try mutableCompositionAudioTrack[0].insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, duration), of: audio, at: kCMTimeZero)
        }catch{
            return nil
        }

        totalVideoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,duration)

        return mixComposition
    }
}
```

Comment: still I am facing same issue.
Actually my code is working for some video and not working for other video

Comment: Your `totalVideoCompositionInstruction` is left unused in your code